# When is the autocorrelation function of a stationary process decreasing/nonincreasing? Markovian?

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-process, stationarity

When is the autocorrelation function of a stationary process strictly decreasing or nonincreasing?
Can being Markovian make it true?

When is the autocorrelation function of a stationary process (strictly) increasing?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is no--but the question becomes more interesting when you replace "decreasing" by "nonincreasing."

Comment: Thanks, @whuber, can you explain why no? What conditions can I add to make it yes? I will add "nonincreasing" to my questions.

Comment: It has to decrease otherwise it would have memory

Comment: @Aksakal: can you prove/explain it?

Comment: I'd have to think about the proof. intuitively if today is correlated with distant past it seems that should contradict the short memory requirement of Markov process.

Comment: Consider these processes and decide whether they are Markov, stationary, and/or have decreasing autocorrelations.  (1) $X$ is any random variable and $X_n = X, n=0, 1, 2, \ldots.$  (2) $X_n$ are iid random variables, $n=0, 1, 2, \ldots.$ (3) $X$ is any symmetric mean-zero random variable and $X_n = (-1)^n X, n=0, 1, 2, \ldots.$

Comment: another example: X=const. right, the correlation doesn't have to decrease to be stationary.

Answer (score 4):

The autocorrelation function $R_X(n)$ of a *stationary* process 
$\{X(t)\colon t \in \mathbb Z\}$, **whether Markovian or not,** is
given by $$R_X(n) = E[X(m)X(m+n)]$$ where, because of stationarity,
the choice of $m$ does not matter: $(X(m), X(m+n))$ has the *same*
joint distribution as $(X(m^\prime), X(m^\prime + n))$ and so
$E[X(m)X(m+n)]= E[X(m^\prime)X(m^\prime+n)]$. Hence,
using an argument which is essentially a version of the
argument that allows us to assert that the Pearson correlation
coefficient $\rho \in [-1,1]$, we get that
$$R_X(0) \geq |R_X(n)|.$$
It is also easy to verify that $R_X(n) = R_X(-n)$ and so, if $R_X(n)$
is an increasing function of $n$ for $n < 0$ (as $R_X(n)$ rises towards its
peak at $0$, say), then $R_X(n)$ must be a decreasing function of $n$ for
$n > 0$. In short, $R_X(n)$ cannot be a strictly increasing function of $n$ for
*all* $n$. What goes up must come down.

The only other possibilities are

1. $R_X(n)=R_X(0)$ for all $n$, that is, the autocorrelation function
   is a constant. An example of such a process is in @whuber's example in the comments on the main question: $X(n) = X$ for all $n$ (Aksakal's suggestion 
   of $X$ being a constant is just a special (degenerate) case of this when
   the random variable $X$ equals a constant almost surely).
2. $R_X(n) = (-1)^n R_X(0)$ for all $n$, that is, the autocorrelation
   function is periodic with period $2$ as in whuber's example in the
   comments where $X(n) = (-1)^nX$ with $X$ being a zero-mean random
   variable with symmetric distribution, that is, $X$ and $-X$ are identically
   distributed and so all the $X(n)$'s have the same distribution (important
   for stationarity).

Comment: +1. I wonder, could we say the for Markovian processes, $R_X(n)$ is non-increasing for $n > 0$?

Answer (score 0):

1. The autocorrelation function of the stationary process does not depend on the time $m$, i.e.

$$R_X(m,n)=E[X(m)X(m+n)] = R_X(n)$$

Then we can make a shift $m\rightarrow m-n$

$$R_X(n) = E[X(m-n)X(m-n+n)] = E[X(m-n)X(m)] = E[X(m)X(m-n)] = R_X(-n)$$

Thus we have the symmetry property

$$R_X(n) = R_X(-n)$$

2. The proof of the non-increasing property is borrowed from Kun Il Park, *Fundamentals of Probability and Stochastic Processes with Applications to Communications*:

$$E[(X(m) - X(m+n))^2] = E[X^2(m) + X^2(m+n) - 2X(m)(m+n)] = 2 E[X^2(m)] + 2E[X(m)(m+n)] \geq 0$$

from which we get

$$E[X^2(m)] \geq E[X(m)(m+n)]$$

or

$$R(0) \geq R(n)$$